# Binding to a NSMutableDictionary and default values

Tags: cocoa, binding, interface-builder, default-value

I've got a couple of controls such as checkbox and radio buttons bound to a `NSMutableDictionary` object on the file owner. The default value of the controls are set in the interface builder, (for example, checkbox should be checked by default) however, those get overriden by the initially empty `NSMutableDictionary`. (Such that checkboxes are no longer checked by default). Is there any way to change this behavior and let the interface builder defaults get written to the NSMutableDictionary automatically? Or would I have to manually setup the defaults in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no way to initialize your dictionary based on settings in IB.

If you *do not* wish the control settings to persist between application runs then add a plist file to your project which defines the default keys/values you wish and then load the `NSMutableDictionary` from that.

If you *do* wish the control settings to persist between application runs then use `NSUserDefaults` and define the default keys/values in the plist file used for its defaults.